# Firefox debugger breakpoint not working

Tags: firefox

When I click on a line to set a break point, the break point line gets highlighted, then the break point highlight disappears.

Other than that, Firefox developer debug has been working fine.

Comment: Is the breakpoint listed in the debugger in the right panel under "breakpoints"?

Comment: thanks MS, i had to COMPLETELY remove firefox and all mozilla folders       
and then reinstall. i could not just you add/remove programs, that dosnt remove enough to make for a total clean install. my breakpoints are working now.  https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/uninstall-firefox-from-your-computer

Comment: Same problem for me. I did not find what causes this. I don't have such issue with the developer edition of Firefox.

Comment: I decided to try chrome for my mvc angular project. it works great, except, sometimes the debugger dosnt show all javascript files. HOWEVER, overall, using the chrome debugger is far more consistant than firefox. if you are using visual studio, you can run that debugger under on the chrome browser. it will display javascript and mvc controller breakpoints. You can use "start without debugging" in visual studio, and then evoke the chrome debugger itself.

Answer (score 38):

This might help people in the future without having to modify any js file:

Have you clicked the `Deactivate breakpoints` button? Pressing this will toggle breakpoints on/off.

[image: deactivate breakpoints icon]

If the icon is in blue, it means the breakpoints will be de-activated.

Note: I have noticed that in some sessions the toggle is activated although not blue, a refresh of the page solved this.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy I found this madness, too. Not to mention that sometimes it's active but doesn't show as active :facepalm:

Answer (score 17):

This just happened to me in `Firefox 60.3.0`. The tip about removing the Mozilla folder led me to a better solution, which is to edit the `prefs.js` file in the Mozilla profile folder. (In my system this was in `C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\xxx.default`)

I deleted all of the lines in prefs.js that began with

**user_pref("devtools.**

e.g.

**user_pref("devtools.toolsidebar-height.inspector", 350);**

**user_pref("devtools.toolsidebar-width.inspector", 350);**

This fixed the problem while preserving all my bookmarks, saved passwords, etc. The lines in prefs.js were recreated when I next ran the debugger.

Comment: This solved the issue for me. Make sure you close Firefox completely before even opening the `prefs.js` file for editing, then save and close the changed file before opening Firefox again.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me — FF 64.0. `)=`

Comment: Worked for me, FF70.0.1, but I think I found the culprit in the process. It would appear the skip pausing button mentioned above doesn't always show the right state. I had it on and then refreshed the page, it was showing as off (also the breakpoints where showing as regular blue instead of pale) but it was actually on in prefs: user_pref("devtools.debugger.skip-pausing", true); Simply turning it on and off seems to fix the problem as well.

Comment: This solved for me. On newer versions of Firefox it's possible to filter the modified properties in the about:config dialog, I just resetted all the modified devtools properties, reloaded the page and voilá.

Answer (score 5):

I my case I have mistakenly enabled 'Blackbox source' on a file (in right click menu). When I disabled it then the breakponts works again.

Comment: I had a file not in the blackbox, but after I put it in the blackbox and then removed, the problem was solved.

Answer (score 3):

**In my case it was 2 check-boxes to check:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem - Firefox Quantum 60 on Ubuntu.

Solution for me was to delete the ~/.mozilla folder for my account.  Lost all my bookmarks, history, settings, etc., but can now set breakpoints again.

Comment: This was my situation exactly (well FFQ 62.0, but still). So far, deleting ~/.mozilla seems to have done the trick for me.

Comment: This is like blowing up your house to shoo out a stray cat.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Walf.  If you have a more elegant solution feel free to include the details below.

Comment: Works also for me

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem, or a variant of it as well. For me, it was because [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) was defaulting to setting [`devtool`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool) to "eval". This broke stopping at breakpoints in Firefox for me. Changing that setting to "source-map" resolved the issue, though I suspect most other non-eval options would work fine as well.

I noticed this because I looked in the generated JS file and noticed everything was put into `eval()` calls.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Also, check the console for errors. I've experienced this issue (can't set a breakpoint) when there is an error elsewhere in the page..

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across a similar problem. In my case, it was the eye on the lower left of the debugger window.

[image]

The breakpoint vanishes after clicking the eye:

[image]

Update:
And another way to blackbox a source:

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that's @madox2's answer, but I activated the "Blackbox source" function in a different way. I'll add the second way to my answer.