# Can't set a breakpoint in Firefox Developer Edition (FDE) 's debugger pane

Tags: breakpoints, firefox-developer-edition

I am running FDE 59.0b12 on Windows 10 64-bit;
I am trying to follow the procedure/video shown at URL: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Set_a_breakpoint in order to debug some JS code within a jQuery.ready() statement.

It seemed easy enough since I used to set breakpoints the same way with the former Firefox+FireBug combo. Except now I can't with FDE. None of the three methods explained works.

e.g. clicking on the line number just doesn't do anything. Same goes for right-clicking on the number, or the line. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Whatever was going wrong has now been merged into the stable version. I did the same as you and now I cannot debug anymore.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53298624/315024) in case it's the same as your issue.

Comment: Possibly-related [Bugzilla ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1441776), from a [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839265/2877364) by [FlorIT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6031876/florit)

Answer (score 2):

I've circumvented the issue by using Firefox 56. It is the last version before 57, therefore before the emergence of Firefox Dev Edition. I won't be using FDE until it gets fixed.