# Firefox Breakpoints are completly disabled

Tags: firefox, breakpoints

Since FF 67 I cannot use breakpoints to debug my javascript on webpages coming from localhost. All breakpoints are completly greyed out so that it is not possible to set any.

I have tried all things in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815123/firefox-debugger-breakpoint-not-working)

- Brekapoints are not deactivated by the deactivate breakpotins button.
- I tried to clear the prefs.js file
- I also tried the checkboxes for pause on exception
- and the checkboxes in the preferences for the dev tools.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also running into this issue.  I found a fix online but it doesn't always work.  Close the debugger window, refresh the page and open the debugger window.  You should be able to set the breakpoints now.  If you refresh while the debugger window is open, you won't be able to set the breakpoints at all.

Doesn't always work, but I was able to test some js code last night

Comment: Hm, I tried this and it worked once! I'll test it a bit more and then mark it as answer

Comment: Hey again M46, update your firefox.  The released an update two days ago and it fixes the break point issue.  Now you can freely set breakpoints everywhere :D

Comment: Hey, your seem to be right. With your answer and the comment. THANK YOU.