# Firefox: debugger: does not stop at breakpoints

Tags: debugging, firefox

There seem to be a lot of postings about this class of problems. Perhaps there is a Mozilla forum where I can ask about this, instead of here?

In my case, I can set breakpoints easily and I can see that they are set. But they are not hit when I refresh the page. Instead, an exception I throw (occurring after the breakpoint) is caught.

EDIT: I found an obscure icon near the top of the window to activate and deactivate the breakpoints! I enabled the breakpoints, but now the page is infinitely looping in some of the debugger's own code and reporting "Paused on exception SyntaxError: '*,:x' is not a valid selector."

I was using the debugger for a Web Extension. Did that put it in a strange mode for regular debugging? How would I get out of this mode?

Question [Firefox debugger breakpoint not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815123/firefox-debugger-breakpoint-not-working) did not help me.

Comment: http://firefox-dev.tools/#getting-in-touch ; this question is hard to answer, since you provide virtually no information about what's wrong...

Comment: Clearly, the error doesn't happen for you. I was not able to create a tiny case that replicated the bug. I've found that the Firefox debugger sometimes requires restarting either Firefox or the computer. In any case, the error is no longer happening for me.

Comment: I'm seeing the issue right now.  I have a console.log and a breakpoint on the same line.  I have dev tools open. I can see the message going to console (it's the only console.log statement I have in my script) but the breakpoint doesn't stop.  I see Firefox exhibiting this behavior from time to time, and I think it's around the time when they want you to update.  I find the constant nag messages very annoying too.  May have to switch to Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but I recently had the same issue and decided to share my solution with the world.

I'm on Firefox 89.0.2 and recently noticed that the debugger does not stop at breakpoints. Completely removing my profile directory and restarting Firefox solved the issue.

To find out the location of your profile folder check the following page from Mozilla: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your solution. It will help me next time this problem happens again.