# react button click not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a little login screen with functional React. I have an input button that I want to click and have the login post happen. For the life of me, I can't get the handler to fire. `loginPressed` just won't get called. I'm sure it's something easy that I'm overlooking.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

export default function Login() {

  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState([]);
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState([]);

  const loginPressed = () => {
    var body = {
      'email': email,
      'password': password
    }
    axios.post('login', body)
         .then(response => {

         })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Username:</p>
      <p><input type="text" name="email" onChange={(e) => {setEmail(e.target.value)}}/></p>
      <p>Password:</p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" onChange={(e) => {setPassword(e.target.value)}}/></p>

      <p>
        <input type='button' value='Login' onClick={loginPressed}/>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: try adding a console log in the beginning of loginPressed to see if the problem is really that the click doesn't trigger the function

Comment: This code works. Are you sure the function isn't calling or are you just having issues with the `axios` request?

Comment: I tried your code. `loginPressed` is called. What is the exact problem?

Comment: The `loginPressed` isn't being hit by a breakpoint in the FireFox debugger.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48815123/firefox-debugger-breakpoint-not-working/54770874)

Comment: hey, your code's working

Answer (score 0):

You should use form with onSubmit={loginPressed}. Instead of input use button html element with type of submit.

Comment: One thing I'm unclear about it forms vs ajax. Are there established use-cases for forms vs ajax that people follow? I chose ajax so that I could use react-router to navigate further.